# Android Transparent status bar and toolbar implementation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, android-4.4-kitkat

[image]

Hi I have implemented the toolbar with translucent statusbar set to true. The textview in the toolbar is appearing correctly after padding the status bar height in "onCreate" method. However, the menu items are not aligned properly as shown in the image.

It seems the padding shifted the toolbar correctly but somehow it affected the menu items. What could be the cause and how could we align the menu item in the toolbar with transparent statusbar?

Here is the toolbar in the layout:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_bg">
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Toolbar Title"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In the theme it was set the translucentStatus = true:

```
<style name="AppThemePink" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:clipToPadding">true</item> ...
```

In the Activity, onCreate method:

```
mainToolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mainToolBar);
    mainToolBar.setPadding(0, Util2.getStatusBarHeight(this), 0, 0);
    final ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Please post your code!

Comment: It seems the padding is applied to the menu item. a walk-around can be to manually set the height of toolbar to accommodate the height of the status bar, but this hack may not be reliable as the height of status bar may differs in different devices.

Comment: if you set the padding in programmatically it is in pixel, i think.

Comment: Yes it is in pixels and i got it like below. How to align the menu item?
int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            result = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }

Comment: @HongZhou did you solve issue?